# Rails: Storing object in variable within multi-tenant application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, multi-tenant

In my multi-tenant application I have model Config which is responsible for each tenant configuration stuff. It has no relation with the tenant, as it is already within the scope of `Tenant.current`. So I just call it as Config.first where needed (I use it in few controllers as well as in few models(as a scope argument)). The problem is that it hits DB each time it's called, but actually most of time it will be unchanged, so I would like to do something like

```
def current_config
  @config ||= Config.first
end
```

but I can not imagine a place for it to be done this way, so I have it 1) stored within one exact tenant; 2) accessable app-wide.

Please share Your suggestions